# How does the react `Router` component communicate with the `Route` component?

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I know that the `Router` component, say `BrowserRouter` creates a history object for keeping track of paths and so on, and that a `Route` component renders its view only when its path matches the current location, which I assume is read from the history. My question is how does the `Route` component get access to the history object that is created by the `BrowserRouter`. Is there some under the hood communication going on that is making this possible?

Answer (score 3):

**This is a context api 'magic'.**

`<BrowserRouter/>` renders `<Router/>`:

```
class BrowserRouter extends React.Component {
  history = createHistory(this.props);

  render() {
    return <Router history={this.history} children={this.props.children} />;
  }
}
```

`<Router/>` renders `<RouterContext.Provider/>`:

```
  <RouterContext.Provider
    children={this.props.children || null}
    value={{
      history: this.props.history,
```

`<Route/>` uses `<RouterContext.Consumer>` to provide access to data from provider.

**Using context api allows to provide data/methods many levels down the tree without the need of passing down props expliticely** (on each level). You can read more about this on [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) or search for tutorials.

Comment: Just the answer I was looking for. You are awesome man, I feel smart already!